# Fatal error occurred when try to startup report engine in birt Viewer Version: 2.5.1

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, birt, birt-emitter

Rocky Linux 8.8
Tomcat server 9
Viewer Version: 4.13.0
Engine Version: 4.13.0
JRE version: 11.0.19

I have received data from the MIS dept provided data of birt reporting which was handled by below configuration

Centos 6
Tomcat server 7
Viewer Version: 2.5.1
Engine Version: 2.5.1
java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64

Home page is displaying fine but view example link shows this error.

```
Fatal error occurred when try to startup report engine.
org.eclipse.birt.report.exception.ViewerException: Fatal error occurred when try to startup report engine.
at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.ReportEngineService.setEngineContext(ReportEngineService.java:328)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.BirtViewerReportService.setContext(BirtViewerReportService.java:1022)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.ViewerServlet.__getContext(ViewerServlet.java:148)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.doGet(BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java:151)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:529)
at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:623)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.service(BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.filter.ViewerFilter.doFilter(ViewerFilter.java:68)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:481)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:673)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:926)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1791)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

does this old configuration will not work with my new server

Thanks.

this is a server log of my system

```
12-Jun-2023 09:14:09.041 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/9.0.76
12-Jun-2023 09:14:09.065 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Jun 5 2023 07:17:04 UTC
12-Jun-2023 09:14:09.066 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version number: 9.0.76.0
12-Jun-2023 09:14:09.066 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
12-Jun-2023 09:14:09.067 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            4.18.0-477.10.1.el8_8.x86_64
12-Jun-2023 09:14:09.067 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
12-Jun-2023 09:14:09.068 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.19.0.7-4.el8.x86_64
12-Jun-2023 09:14:09.084 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           11.0.19+7-LTS
12-Jun-2023 09:14:09.084 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Red Hat, Inc.
12-Jun-2023 09:14:09.085 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /opt/tomcat
12-Jun-2023 09:14:09.085 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /opt/tomcat
12-Jun-2023 09:14:09.233 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
12-Jun-2023 09:14:09.234 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
12-Jun-2023 09:14:09.234 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
12-Jun-2023 09:14:09.235 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED
12-Jun-2023 09:14:09.235 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
12-Jun-2023 09:14:09.236 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/tomcat/conf/logging.properties
12-Jun-2023 09:14:09.236 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
12-Jun-2023 09:14:09.236 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/urandom
12-Jun-2023 09:14:09.237 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
12-Jun-2023 09:14:09.237 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
12-Jun-2023 09:14:09.237 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027
12-Jun-2023 09:14:09.238 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xms512M
12-Jun-2023 09:14:09.238 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xmx1024M
12-Jun-2023 09:14:09.238 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -XX:+UseParallelGC
12-Jun-2023 09:14:09.239 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
12-Jun-2023 09:14:09.239 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/opt/tomcat
12-Jun-2023 09:14:09.239 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/opt/tomcat
12-Jun-2023 09:14:09.240 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/tomcat/temp
12-Jun-2023 09:14:09.251 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows using OpenSSL was not found on the java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib]
12-Jun-2023 09:14:11.743 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
12-Jun-2023 09:14:11.981 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Server initialization in [5005] milliseconds
12-Jun-2023 09:14:12.606 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
12-Jun-2023 09:14:12.606 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.76]
12-Jun-2023 09:14:12.732 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/opt/tomcat/webapps/birt.war]
12-Jun-2023 09:14:49.169 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
12-Jun-2023 09:14:54.099 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/opt/tomcat/webapps/birt.war] has finished in [40,689] ms
12-Jun-2023 09:14:54.101 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/docs]
12-Jun-2023 09:14:54.184 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/docs] has finished in [82] ms
12-Jun-2023 09:14:54.184 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/manager]
12-Jun-2023 09:14:54.322 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/manager] has finished in [138] ms
12-Jun-2023 09:14:54.323 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/ROOT]
12-Jun-2023 09:14:54.371 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/ROOT] has finished in [47] ms
12-Jun-2023 09:14:54.372 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/examples]
12-Jun-2023 09:14:54.912 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/examples] has finished in [539] ms
12-Jun-2023 09:14:54.913 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/host-manager]
12-Jun-2023 09:14:54.990 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/host-manager] has finished in [77] ms
12-Jun-2023 09:14:54.991 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/ReportEngine]
12-Jun-2023 09:14:55.046 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/ReportEngine] has finished in [55] ms
12-Jun-2023 09:14:55.046 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/WebViewerExample]
12-Jun-2023 09:15:10.945 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
12-Jun-2023 09:15:11.534 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/WebViewerExample] has finished in [16,487] ms
12-Jun-2023 09:15:11.534 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/about_files]
12-Jun-2023 09:15:11.570 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/about_files] has finished in [35] ms
12-Jun-2023 09:15:11.571 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/mis]
12-Jun-2023 09:15:11.611 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/mis] has finished in [41] ms
12-Jun-2023 09:15:11.612 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/bank]
12-Jun-2023 09:15:13.560 INFO [main] java.util.ArrayList.forEach Name = MySqlDB Ignoring unknown property: value of "Resource reference to a factory for java.sql.Connection" for "description" property
12-Jun-2023 09:15:14.165 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
12-Jun-2023 09:15:15.756 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/opt/tomcat/webapps/bank] has finished in [4,143] ms
12-Jun-2023 09:15:15.775 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
12-Jun-2023 09:15:15.855 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [63873] milliseconds
12-Jun-2023 09:24:46.052 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-9] org.apache.axis.configuration.FileProvider.check Configuration file read-only so engine configuration changes will not be saved.
12-Jun-2023 09:24:46.226 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-9] org.apache.axis.utils.JavaUtils.isAttachmentSupported Unable to find required classes (javax.activation.DataHandler and javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart). Attachment support is disabled.
```

Comment: Was there more in the server's log? Not everything is shown to the client.